How to alter a function with dozens of dependencies?
I need to change a function that already has dozens of dependencies. I'm not changing the input parameters or result of that function, only how it calculates its result. But even without changing the public interface of that function, trying to alter the function still gets an error that it cannot be altered because it has dependencies (mainly default constraints).
Is there a command modifier or tool to change that function without having to drop all its dependencies and re-creating them at the end (it will take me hours to write such script, knowing that I will probably have to repeat this process in a few weeks).
This was already asked over 10 years ago, without a solution, but I ask again because a lot has changed in 10 years in SQL Server, and I use a much modern version of it.
How do I alter a T-SQL FUNCTION with a dependent default constraint?

If you use dacpac deployments it should figure out the dependencies and generate a script that takes account of these

@MartinSmith I didn't know that tool, but I going to check it right now. Thank you.

The tool is actually SQL Server Database Tools, introduced sometimes around 2005/2007 (can't remember). You can reverse engineer the entire database into a Database Project and find dependencies, check for problems, generate the project schema with actual databases and generate deployment or diff scripts. It also has a limited set of refactorings, like renaming

As for the other question, it did get an answer. There's no simple way to do that. In many cases you have to drop and rebuild constraints. SSDT automates the script creation, it doesn't disable it. Having a function with dozens of dependencies is a bit of a smell anyway. The fact the parameters don't change doesn't mean much. The important objects are the actual tables, columns, their types and constraints. SQL as a language is pretty strongly typed. If you use SCHEMABINDING to allow certain features, it becomes a lot stricter

@PanagiotisKanavos I like the fact that SQL Server is strong typed, but I'm not changing any type whatsoever, I'm only trying to change the internal calculations within the function. Not types, not adding parameters, not tables, not columns, not constraints, nothing that you said.

@PanagiotisKanavos I will check these SQL Server Database Tools. Thank you. Looks like I'll have to install a full Visual Studio to get them :-(

Or install Azure Data Studio, which has a slightly different version of Database Projects. You haven't explained what you want to do though. If you want to do something that affects multiple other objects you do need something that can detect the other objects, find the differences and generate change scripts. That requires a lot of tools. IDEs were built to coordinate all those tools.

Wiki answer because fiddle seems down and i didn't wanna paste the whole shebang into a comment
If your function would call another function which does the actual calcs, it seems to avoid the issue.
create OR ALTER function dbo.Y_FUNC (
)
returns int
as
begin
    return(0)
end

GO

create OR ALTER function dbo.X_FUNC (
)
returns int
as
begin
    return(dbo.Y_FUNC())
end

GO

create table t_x (i int not null default dbo.X_FUNC())

go

CREATE OR alter function Y_FUNC (
)
returns INT
as
begin
    return(1)
end

It might not help you this time, but next time you need to change stuff :)

Thanks. It's a good solution to bypass that absurd lock. I will change all my default constraints to call a bridge function, so in the future I will be able to alter whenever I like the real function that calculates those values.
